# Bibliography trouble

Tags: bibliographies

I am NOT v.g. at this stuff so would be grateful for any replies to be written in VERY simple and easy-to-follow format. Thanks.

You will see, below, the first few lines of my work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{plain}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{headings}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\newcommand{\bm}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath{$#1$}}}
\begin{document}
\bibliography{With Bibliography}
\author{Dr. Glyn Williams}
```

I am trying to include \cite references in the body of the work. I have compiled both .bib and .bbl files. 
I get a list beginning with:

```
@article{Abramovitz,
    Author = {Abramovitz and Stegan},
    Date-Added = {2016-07-05 4:34:28 pm +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-07-05 4:37:31 pm +0000},
    Journal = {National Bureau of Standards, Applied Mathematics Series, Washington D.C.},
    Title = {Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs and Mathematical Tables},
    Volume = {55},
    Year = {1965}}

@article{Arnaud1,
    Author = {Arnaud},
    Date-Added = {2016-07-05 3:29:29 pm +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-07-09 10:21:07 am +0000},
    Journal = {Academic Press Inc. (London)},
    Title = {Beam and Fibre Optics},
    Year = {1976}}
```

When I convert the work to a pdf I find that the references occur similar to: Dicke[?] and there is nothing in the [ ]. It seems to me that the system has not compiled but I do not know what I am not doing.

Sorry to be so dim but this is not one of my fortes!
Look forward to receiving your comments.
Thanks.
Dr. W.

Comment: `\bibliography{databasename}` takes the name of your database, and it should not contain any stange symbols like spaces.

Comment: Did follow the whole cycle `pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex (twice)`? Just in case, add `\nocite{*}`to the body of your document.

Comment: Off topic: Your reference management tool is utter rubbish. Look what it puts in the journal fields. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: There seem to be no `\cite`-like instructions in your document. How do you expect LaTeX and BibTeX to build a bibliography if there are no pieces being cited?

Comment: the MWE is incomplete. please provide a fully compilable one.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I shall endeavour to use them and, hopefully, they will produce the desired result!

Answer (score 2):

Your bib file is an appalling mess and the code in your tex file cannot possibly generate a formatted bibliography.

About the entries in the bib file:

- Both entries you are showing are books - *why* are they given type `@article` instead of `@book`?
- The surnames of both authors of the first entry are mis-spelled. It's "Abramowitz", not "Abramovitz". And, it's "Stegun", not "Stegan". Really, how much more difficult can it be to spell names correctly than it is to introduce random spelling mistakes?
- The first names of all authors are missing
- The title of the second entry contains yet another spelling error. It's "Fiber", not "Fibre". (Yes, it's spelled "Fiber" even though the publisher is based in London...)
- The year of the first publication is 1964, not 1965.
- Many of the fields in the two entries are utterly unsuitable for books -- and for journal articles as well, for that matter. See the code below for an attempt to rectify things a bit.

I can only surmise that you're using a dreadfully poor and inadequate piece of software to build the bib entries. Get rid of it, immediately! You'll save yourself a lot of time building the bib entries by hand. Better still, do get a better software tool.

About the latex file itself:

- There are no `\cite`-like commands. How do you expect BibTeX and LaTeX to know how to create the bibliography if nothing at all is being cited?
- The argument of `\bibliography` should be a name of a file with extension `.bib`. E.g., if the bib file is named `mybib.bib`, you should write `\bibliography{mybib}`. Observe: no filename extension is given in the argument of `\bibliography`.
- The `plain` bibliography style generates numeric-style citation call-outs. Is that what you want?

Here, then, is an attempt to create a minimal but correct bibliography.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{Abramowitz,
    Author    = {Milton Abramowitz and Irene Ann Stegun},
    Publisher = {National Bureau of Standards},
    Address   = {Washington D.C.},
    Title     = {Handbook of Mathematical Functions with 
                 Formulas, Graphs and Mathematical Tables},
    Series    = {Applied Mathemathics Series},
    Number    = {55},
    Year      = {1964}
}
@book{Arnaud1,
    Author    = {J. A. Arnaud},
    Publisher = {Academic Press},
    Address   = {London},
    Title     = {Beam and Fiber Optics},
    Year      = {1976}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\cite{Abramowitz}, \cite{Arnaud1}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I shall endeavour to use them and, hopefully, they will produce the desired result!

Comment: Hello, again. Before I struggle with trying to apply your comments please let me know if I am using the appropriate software for the job...

Comment: I have downloaded a TEX app for a MacBookPro but, clearly, the file for adding bib entries seems to be inappropriate. I notice that one comment has pointed out that I should not have any gaps in the .bib name. Where do I acquire the necessary to write files as shown by each of you? Thanks. PS If you want any help with Theoretical physics then I shall try to oblige! :) Apologies for poor spelling, etc. That is the LEAST of my worries.

Comment: There are \cite instructions but not in the extract I posted.

Comment: @Dr.GlynWilliams - Are you asking about editors that let you create text files?

Comment: Yes please. Can you recommend something for a MacBook? Thanks.

Comment: At the moment I use Bibdesk. Do you know of it?

Comment: @Dr.GlynWilliams - I've heard of Bibdesk, but I don't use it myself. Be aware, though, that Bibdesk is just a front-end: It won't prevent the creation of wildly inaccurate bib entries (e.g., inappropriate entry types, mis-spelled surnames, missing first names, incorrect publication years, etc). In the end, it's still your responsibility to check if the information you've gathered up is correct.

Comment: Many thanks. Will plough (English spelling) on today!

Comment: What do you recommend for a MacBook?

Comment: @Dr.GlynWilliams - I take it you already have a full MacTeX distribution, which comes with Bibdesk, I believe. The tools are fine -- just make an effort to learn how to use these tools effectivelz.

Comment: THANKS to ALL who have provided comments and help. I have managed to sort things out and the bibliography has appeared. WHY are things so difficult? I never had this trouble with Q.M. (But, as Feynman used to say, "If you think you understand Q.M. you don't understand Q.M!" I really do think that computer manuals and software guides seem to be written for particular classes of people and there seems to be a widening gap between the C.P. Snow's "Two Cultures" sections. Anyway. Once again, MANY THANKS. As Macarthur (I think?) said, "I shall return". For more help!